# How to place some text in the pie hole of doughnut chart in google sheets by using apps script without html/css/js?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet which has some data and I am dynamically creating a doughnut chart using apps script.

```
    function newDonutChart(sheet, color) {
    
    var chart = sheet.newChart()
        .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.PIE)
    .addRange(sheet.getRange("Z1:Z2"))
    .setPosition(START_ROW_NUM+21, 2, 0, 0)
    .setOption("pieHole", 0.7)
    .setOption("pieSliceText", "percentage")
    .setOption("colors", [color, "#DCDCDC"])
    .setOption("width", 120)
    .setOption("height", 120)
        .build();
    sheet.insertChart(chart);
    }
```

It creates the below chart in sheet after running the above code

[image]

Till here all good but now I need to place some text inside the pie hole but I did not find any option/method to do it in apps script.
Please note that I am not creating a web app, it is simply a script which runs and output is rendered on google sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, Just have to make the background color of chart as none so that the text behind the chart in the cell of the google sheet can be seen

```
        .setOption("backgroundColor", "none")
```